# unable to read the reply of query on whatsapp through twilio API

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am sending an autoresponse to the message 'Hi' on WhatsApp through twilio API. Using switch statement as shown below.

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  
  const receievedMessage = req.body;
  console.log(receievedMessage);
  // console.log(receievedMessage.From);
  const from = receievedMessage.From;
  const query  = receievedMessage.Body;
  console.log(query);
  const msgText = `${query}, Welcome to Ohphish.Fortifying Frontlines.Protect your workforce from Phishing attacks for FREE`;
  const msgText2 = 'Kindly Enter Your Registered Mobile Number';


function sendWithDelay(){
  setTimeout(() => {
    sendMessage(msgText2,from);
  },2000)
}

  switch(query){
    case 'Hi':
    case 'hi':
    case 'HI':
    case 'Hello':
    case 'hello':
    case 'HELLO':
      {
      sendMessage(msgText,from);
      sendWithDelay();
      }
       break;
      default:
        sendMessage('Sorry, Wrong Query', from)

  }
```

I am sending two auto responses first is WelcomeMessage and second is a message to provide registered mobile number. When the mobile number is given the message I get is the default case of switch. My target is to send the same number with a message as Number entered by you is [number]

Send Message defination is given is below

```
module.exports = sendMessage =  (msgText,to) => { 
       client.messages 
      .create({ 
         body: msgText,             
         from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',       
         to: to 
       }) 
      .then(message => {
            console.log(message.sid);
      }) 
      .done();
      
}
```

Comment: The structure of your case statement is incorrect. Reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: I have shared screenshot without break. Sorry for that but I have also checked giving break above default. I have also run with if else but still the same output. Kindly suggest my next mistake...